# Extra white space below html body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on an angular js app that consists of a swipeable carousel populated with data taken from a json array (which is held in a js var). However, I have run into an issue; a large amount of white space appears at the bottom of the page. I cannot seem to determine the cause of this extra white space. I have padding and margins set to 0 in the css. When I inspect the element the white space appears to be outside of the html so it seems almost as if its not even being added by a property of one of my elements.

heres my **css** but there is a full plunk linked at the bottom as well

```
html, body, #carousel, #carousel ul, #carousel li {
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
}

#link{
position: absolute;
bottom:20px;
right:20px;
}

#carousel {
background: white;

 width: 100%;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

 #carousel ul.animate {
 -webkit-transition: all .3s;
 -moz-transition: all .3s;
 -o-transition: all .3s;
 transition: all .3s;
 }

 #carousel ul {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
-o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#carousel ul {

position: relative;
}

#carousel li {
float: left;
width:100%;  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#carousel li h2 {
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#carousel li.pane1 {
background: #fff;
}

#carousel li.pane2 {
background: #fff;
}

#carousel li.pane3 {
background: #fff;
}


#carousel li.pane4 {
background: #fff;
}


.january { 
background-color:#ffe0b0;
height:8.33%;
}
.february { 
background-color:#b0f7ff;
height:8.33%;
}
.march { 
background-color:#e0b0ff;
height:8.33%;
}
.april { 
background-color:#ffb9b0;
height:8.33%;
}
.may { 
background-color:#b0cfff;
height:8.33%;
}
.june { 
background-color:#b0ffe0;
height:8.33%;
}
.july { 
background-color:#ffb0f7;
height:8.33%;
}
.august { 
background-color:#ceffb0;
height:8.33%;
}
.september { 
background-color: #ffb0cf;
height:8.33%;
}
.october { 
background-color:#bab0ff;
height:8.33%;
}
.november { 
background-color:#f6ffb0;
height:8.33%;
}
.december { 
background-color: #b0f6ff; 
height:8.33%;
}

.day {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Regular', serif; 
  color:#000; 
  text-align: center;
 }
 .titletext {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%; 
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  display:inline-block;
  }
  .title {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: initial;
  }
  .quote {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display Italic', serif; 
     font-style: italic; 
    font-size:12px; 
    margin-top:10px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right: 20px;
line-height:1.2em;
 }
 .attribution {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display Regular', serif; 

    font-size:10px;
margin-left:25px;
margin-right: 20px;
line-height:1.2em;
}
.textt {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display Regular', serif; 

    font-size:12px; 
    margin-top:10px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right: 20px;
line-height:1.2em;
 }
 .date {
font-family: 'Playfair Display Regular', serif; 
margin-left:15px;
padding-top: 10px;
}
#circleJan {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #ffe0b0;
background-color:#ffe0b0;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleFeb {
border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid #b0f7ff;
background-color:#b0f7ff;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleMarch {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #e0b0ff;
background-color:#e0b0ff;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
} 
#circleApril {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #ffb9b0;
background-color:#ffb9b0;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleMay {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #b0cfff;
background-color:#b0cfff;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleJune {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #b0ffe0;
background-color:#b0ffe0;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleJuly {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #ffb0f7;
background-color:#ffb0f7;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleAug {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #ceffb0;
background-color:#ceffb0;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleSept {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #ffb0cf;
background-color:#ffb0cf;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleOct {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #bab0ff;
background-color:#bab0ff;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleNov {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #f6ffb0;
background-color:#f6ffb0;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
#circleDec {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #b0f6ff;
background-color:#b0f6ff;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
margin-left:15px;
}
.bg{}
.main{height:100%}
.heading{
 font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
 text-align:center;
 margin-top: 10px; 
 font-size:18px;
}
.stepOne{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px;
}
.stepTwo{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 .stepThree{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 .stepFour{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 .stepFive{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 .stepSix{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 .stepSeven{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px; 
 }
 .stepEight{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 .stepNine{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 .stepTen{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif; 
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 .stepEleven{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif;  
  margin-left:50px; 
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 .stepTwelve{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display Bold', serif;  
  margin-left:50px;  
  margin-right:15px;
 }
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/quDsLRMbbOlHwCIKcvil?p=preview)

Comment: Where exactly is your whitespace? All I can see is the `div`'s padding.

Comment: use chrome debugger (F12) and then right-click on the white-space and you'll see which DOM element is causing the issue. You can then change the css in the debugger to eliminate the issue.

Comment: If I understand what white space you are talking about, it's because `.panel1` has a `min-height` and `height` of `100%`, taking up screen space.

Comment: Just a reminder to either consider marking accepted any of the answers you may be satisfied with, or revising your question to both better clarify your problem as well its bump its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your `#carousel li` is currently being set at a `height: 100%` which is causing the extra space in your first pane.

I would also strongly advise refactoring your CSS to more concise organization since I noticed a lot of repetitive code. The simplest example of this is `.stepOne` through `.stepTwelve` which all contain the same styles. Collapse that into one class and apply it across all the elements needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the white space after the `pane1` element, you can get rid of of it by setting its `height` and `min-height` to `initial`:

```
#carousel li.pane1 {
  height: initial;
  min-height: initial;
  background: #fff;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/afV0gSFXUAcKKLggztYU?p=preview)

I should mention, in a lot of instances you're using classes when you should be using IDs. If there's only one `.january` element for example, set it as an ID rather than a class, as classes are meant for grouping multiple elements. The same goes for your `pane[x]` classes. You should also merge your identical styles, e.g.

```
#pane2, #pane3, #pane4 {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Or if you simply give them all the same class:

```
.pane {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that surely removes the extra space I was talking about. I had a hamburger icon, however, with the id `#link` which was at the bottom of the  window. Do you have any idea how I could retain the positioning of this element? Here is an update [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0JtmMhOsK7YiJ82anNa?p=preview) with the icon represented.

Comment: [Sure, just give it some `padding-bottom`.](http://plnkr.co/edit/gHpoCdBKakWEiOoVPERf?p=preview)